# Ускорить file get contents

Tags: php

При использовании `file_get_contents` внутри `while` идет задержка 5-10 секунд есть какое то решение? Надо ускорить процесс как-то).

> file_get_contents Читает:

```
while (true) {
    $String = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=D809927A12701C14A968491B9518BBB6&steamids=76561198212513347");
    $mail   = explode('                ', $String);
    $mail   = explode('"', $mail[8]);
    $mail   = $mail[3];
    if ($mail == '') {
        $mail = '../img/no-avatar.jpg';
    }
    echo $mail;
}
```

Comment: Что читает `file_get_contents`? Было бы здорово увидеть чуть больше кода

Comment: Думаю эта проблема из-за скорости ответа

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы найти мыло Вам лушче использовать json_decode, во-вторых зачем читать статическую информацию в бесконечном цикле?

Comment: Я проста не писал `while ($prof = mysql_fetch_array($pro)) `

Answer (score 2):

Время `file_get_contents` тратит на http-запрос.

Поэтому, чтобы ускорить его, нужно подключить очень быстрый интернет. Хороший канал связи должен быть от вашего сервера до конечного узла. Заставить чужой сервер отвечать быстрее вы не сможете)

Comment: Или проста использовать CURL хотябы чуть быстрее работает )

Comment: curl не быстрее - одинаково) Просто в curl больше опций можно задавать, заголовки получать, а не только body.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно при обращении происходят редиректы, по этому и ожидание долгое.
Еще можно попробовать заменить на CURL или Soket. Быстрее работает.

Comment: Я сравнил ответы показали: от file_get_contents Время: 0.34765291214s . CURL Время:  0.271059989929s.Но иногда при перезагурзке CURL выскакивает на 0.7...

Comment: Попробуйте глянуть в каком режиме запущен php, случайно не в  without-curl ?

Comment: @Sauron, ну так если у вас время выполнения запроса 0.34765291214 то что мы оптимизурем?

Comment: Тут показан пример над одним запросом если выводить через while 10 раз то выводит в течении 5-10 секунд.То есть это долго ...